# Entity Framework - Disconnected Contexts and Duplicate Records

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am using Entity Framework 6. When I update a navigation property to an object and then execute SaveChanges(), rather than referencing the existing the object, it creates a duplicate in the reference table.

I have some examples below:

The following example works as expected. It creates a "Customer" and an "Order" and successfully associates them:

```
// Homer Simpson buys some Duff beer

Console.WriteLine("Homer Simpson is buying Duff beer");

Customer customer = new Customer
{
    Name = "Homer Simpson"
};

Order order1 = new Order
{
    Description = "Duff Beer"
};

customer.Orders.Add(order1);

using (EFContext db = new EFContext())
{
    db.Customers.Add(customer);
    DisplayChanges(db);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

**Output**

```
Homer Simpson is buying Duff beer
ConsoleApplication1.Objects.Customer - Added
ConsoleApplication1.Objects.Order - Added
```

However, if I try to then add an order and associate my existing customer, when I save my changes it duplicates the Customer object in the DB as well as the existing order which I had created:

```
// Homer Simpson buys some Duff beer

Console.WriteLine("Homer Simpson is buying Duff beer");

Customer customer = new Customer
{
    Name = "Homer Simpson"
};

Order order1 = new Order
{
    Description = "Duff Beer"
};

customer.Orders.Add(order1);

using (EFContext db = new EFContext())
{
    db.Customers.Add(customer);
    DisplayChanges(db);
    db.SaveChanges();
}

// Homer Simpson buys some Buzz Cola

Console.WriteLine("\r\nHomer Simpson is buying Buzz Cola");

Order order2 = new Order
{
    Description = "Buzz Cola",
    Customer = customer
};

using (EFContext db = new EFContext())
{
    db.Orders.Add(order2);
    DisplayChanges(db);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

**Output**

```
Homer Simpson is buying Duff beer
ConsoleApplication1.Objects.Customer - Added
ConsoleApplication1.Objects.Order - Added

Homer Simpson is buying Buzz Cola
ConsoleApplication1.Objects.Order - Added
ConsoleApplication1.Objects.Customer - Added
ConsoleApplication1.Objects.Order - Added
```

If I set the Foreign Key as opposed to the Navigation Property, the record is not duplicated. However, in this scenario I do not have access to the properties of the related object until I explicitly load it:

```
// Homer Simpson buys some Duff beer

Console.WriteLine("Homer Simpson is buying Duff beer");

Customer customer = new Customer
{
    Name = "Homer Simpson"
};

Order order1 = new Order
{
    Description = "Duff Beer"
};

customer.Orders.Add(order1);

using (EFContext db = new EFContext())
{
    db.Customers.Add(customer);
    DisplayChanges(db);
    db.SaveChanges();
}

// Homer Simpson buys some donuts

Console.WriteLine("\r\nHomer Simpson is buying donuts");

Order order3 = new Order
{
    Description = "Donuts",
    CustomerID = 1
};

if (order3.Customer == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Customer is null before save!");
}

else
{
    Console.WriteLine("The customer is " + customer.Name + " before save!");
}

using (EFContext db = new EFContext())
{
    db.Orders.Add(order3);
    DisplayChanges(db);
    db.SaveChanges();
}

if (order3.Customer == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Customer is null after save!");
}

else
{
    Console.WriteLine("The customer is " + customer.Name + " after save!");
}

using (EFContext db = new EFContext())
{
    db.Orders.Attach(order3);
    db.Entry(order3).Reference(x => x.Customer).Load();
}

if (order3.Customer == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Customer is null after forced load!");
}

else
{
    Console.WriteLine("The customer is " + customer.Name + " after forced load!");
}
```

**Output**

```
Homer Simpson is buying Duff beer
ConsoleApplication1.Objects.Customer - Added
ConsoleApplication1.Objects.Order - Added

Homer Simpson is buying donuts
Customer is null before save!
ConsoleApplication1.Objects.Order - Added
Customer is null after save!
The customer is Homer Simpson after forced load!
```

Is anyone able to offer any advice? I understand that you can Attach and Detach entities manually, but that being said, I am working with some quite complicated objects. I would like to find a simple way to control the Change Tracking in Entity Framework.

Regards

Peter Deegan

Comment: No simple way - working with disconnected object graphs never was easy/simple in EF. You can give a try to [GraphDiff](https://github.com/refactorthis/GraphDiff) package which was trying to address the subject. Unfortunately it's no more supported by the author.

Answer (score 0):

When you are **attaching** customer object to order 2 it is inserting a new customer object, I think you should be using foreign key always instead of attaching the entity, and for loading the property part, of course you won't get the customer object attached to order, since you just inserted it
if you check `public virtual <T> Add(T entity)` as you can see it return the object itself, without including any other objects, customer object won't be loaded until you do load it which make sense I guess, in your example you used explicit load to load customer object, if you want to avoid that you can enable lazy loading and always get the customer object without explicitly loading it. in brief, always use fk, and when you need the entity load it (lazy loading or explicit), attaching objects is never good practice unless you want to insert all of them together, or you don't care about duplicates.
I hope this helped.